# "Object-Fit: Contain" not working on Android Web Browser

Tags: android, css, wordpress, woocommerce

There is a category page with thumbnails on Woocommerce website. 
All thumbnails are of variable sizes but in appropriate aspect ratio.

The `object-fit:contain` works fine Firefox.

Here is the style I'm using to correctly center align those thumbnails inside a div.

```
img {
display:block;
left:50%;
top:50%;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
max-height:100%
position:absolute;
object-fit:contain;
max-width:101%;
width:auto;
height:auto;
}
```

**1.** It does not work on Android's default Web Browser. Images fit in height but on width - they're stretched.

[image]

**2.** Images look slightly blur on Chrome only, especially when using `object-fit:contain`. If i remove it, they work nice.

Comment: AFAIK [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) is an experimental feature that doesn't work on all browsers. You'd be better setting the image as a background with `background-size:cover`.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit says it supports android above version 4.4.4. Which version of android are you testing it on?

Comment: Thanks @dingo_d I'll try that. @ Arathi, I've tried it on several devices. All of them on Lollipop or Marshmallow.

Comment: @ArathiSreekumar Problem is not with Firefox. But with the default Android browser. Especially when a link is opened through Facebook app. I suppose it loads default system browser overlay.

Comment: @dingo_d how can we use `background-size` for `img src` tag?

Comment: As per the mdn it is supposed to work on the android browser of lollipop and marshmallow, not sure why it isn't. As it's still experimental, there is no guarantee I suppose.

Comment: I guess. You're right. Maybe that's why the results are inconsistent. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) is not yet widely used css property, the better alternative is to use [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) image.

Something like this:

```css
.myimage {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myimage" style="background:url(https://placehold.it/350x150) no-repeat center center; background-size:cover; min-height:300px;"></div>
```

Now there is an apparent drawback of this method - the image size is not something that will be automatically set. So if you don't specify the `min-height` of the div container, you won't see anything. You can either crop your images to the same size, so that you know what the image size should be, or try to extract it from the image somehow.

The up side of this method is the uniformity - all the images in your blog/shop/portfolio category will be the same size, no matter the image you've uploaded. Also you can put text over it if you want to.

You can get the image metadata in WordPress using [`wp_get_attachment_metadata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata). From that you could put the native image size in the element container.